# Apply toUpperCase() on capture group (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

I have the string:`<upcase>yellow submarine</upcase>`
And I want to modify it to: `YELLOW SUBMARINE` using regular expressions.

What I have tried so far is:

```
var modified = string.replace(/<upcase>(.*?)<\/upcase>/gi, $1.toUpperCase());
```

And...

```
var modified = string.replace(/<upcase>(.*?)<\/upcase>/gi, "\U$1");
```

Obviously both methods won't work, so what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Pass a callback to `.replace`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** to get "YELLOW SUBMARINE" only

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for explanation

```js
var str = '<upcase>yellow submarine</upcase>';
str = str.replace(/<upcase>(.*?)<\/upcase>/gi, function(){return arguments[1].toUpperCase()});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Better than my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I found the solution myself. In case anyone's interested:

```
var str = '<upcase>yellow submarine</upcase>';
str = str.replace(/<upcase>(.*?)<\/upcase>/gi, function (v) {
    return v.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "").toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) (as I noted in my comment to your question), then you will see that the value of each capture group is passed to the callback as argument. So you can write: `str.replace(/<upcase>(.*?)<\/upcase>/gi, function (match, g) { return g.toUpperCase(); })` instead.